# How to get the Pass/Fail status of student in Informatica

Tags: output, informatica

[image]

Based on the given marks for each student in different subjects. Student is marked as failed if marks in any subject is less than 30.

I want to see if student has passed or failed using Informatica PowerCenter.

Input:
Please see the image of Student table

My approach is to normalize the input data as below:
A 50,80,60
b 29,45,50

Then use substring to see if any value seperated by comma(,) is less than 30, then Mark his as Fail.

Please suggest.

DESIRED OUTPUT:
A  PASS
B  FAIL

Answer (score 0):

Just use an aggregator grouped by studentid returning min(Marks). The next transformation would be an expression to set a boolean based on whether the min value passed from the aggregator is above 30 or not. Is this your homework?